# UILabel and right to left text

Tags: cocoa-touch

I have a collection of NSString objects that contain arabic text. However, when I try to display any of them using a UILabel, the text shows left-to-right instead of right-to-left (NSLog shows the strings properly)

I am thinking about a work-around, applying a transform to the UILabel to make a y-axis symmetry, but how can I detect if a NSString contains a RTL string?

Answer (score 1):

Try prepending the unicode character 0x200F to the beginning of each string. This character is an invisible marker character that indicates text directionality.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your region to Arabic? I would have thought this type of thing would be handled automatically.

Comment: Thanks Andrew

The problem is that I can not force the users to change their region. And it should be automatically handled, as it is in OS X, but...